# How reliable is Denmark's post restante service? How much does it cost?

Tags: denmark, mail

It seems I can receive a letter using Denmark's [post restante service](https://www.postnord.dk/en/receiving/poste-restante). Does anyone know how reliable it is? Can I receive a 4kg package? How much does it cost (I couldn't understand the pricing page)?

Comment: It's been decades since I've had any reason to use Post Restate services but I've never been aware of a charge and I see nothing on that page that suggests there is a charge.  (That is, beyond the charge for simply mailing it.)

Comment: I wouldn't think it costs extra, but you can probably contact them via support and report back with an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, it works perfectly. You basically find the address of the post office you want to receive the package in, mail it there with your name and then they email/text you a magic number to show when you pick it up. My only complaint is that the Nordpost support number doesn't work, I waited for 40 minutes and no one picked up. Still, in the end it wasn't necessary.